# JDBC getObject on table user returns error : "access to class (class) is prohibited"

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I am having a weird response while trying to get all columns of users in the table "user" of my "mysql" database.

I am using Google Cloud SQL, accessing it from Google Apps Script with the JDBC class. Here is my code :

```
function displayingOneUser(){

  var connection = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://blablabla/mysql", "root", rootPwd);

  var mySqlStatement = connection.createStatement();

  var resultSet = mySqlStatement.executeQuery("select * from user");

  if(resultSet.next()){
    var str="";
    for(var i=1; i<43; i++){
      str=str.concat(resultSet.getObject(i)+" | ");
      Logger.log("str so far : "+str);
    }
    Logger.log("Displaying first user : "+str+".");
  }

  mySqlStatement.close();
  connection.close();


}
```

I get the following error : "Access to class "(class)" is prohibited.", when it reaches column 33 or 34 (I don't remember which one).
If I use getString(), then it works without a problem.

Any idea where that could come from ?

Cheers,

Victor

Comment: Btw, I tried putting some resultSet.next() in the beginning, to see whether starting with another user would change something. It doesn't. It always fails at the first user for which it tries to access column 33 (or 34)

Comment: To check - is the column that the script is complaining about called "class"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this problem and I believe this is indeed a bug. This has to do with `blob` columns in the `user` table in the default `mysql` DB

[image]

Trying to read any of those columns with `getObject()` breaks. `getString()` works.

Good find, please log a bug in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) so we can dig into this.

Its column 34, `ssl_cipher` that is the first `blob` column that breaks. Others break too. Simplest repro case -

```
function displayingOneUser(){
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://INSTANCE_NAME/mysql");
  var sql = conn.createStatement();
  var resultSet = sql.executeQuery("select ssl_cipher from user");
  if(resultSet.next()){
    resultSet.getObject(1);//this line will break
  }
  sql.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Arun ! Great, that makes a lot of sense ! Thank you. I will file an issue, and in the meantime I'll use a try catch.

Comment: I posted the issue here http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2446&thanks=2446&ts=1361164812

Comment: Thanks. Please close out this question as we'll now track the issue tracker item.

Comment: Hi Arun. Ok I will. Sorry I can't find how to close it out. Can you tell me how ?

Comment: No problem - I think I used confusing wording. You should "accept" the answer by checking the checkbox on the left side of the answer.